# Task never defined: style

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I run: npm install gulp gulp-sass gulp-autoprefixer browser-sync --save-dev

And then I have this in the gulpfile.js

```
const gulp         = require('gulp')
const sass         = require('gulp-sass')
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer') 
const browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create()

function style() {
    return gulp.src(["./src/sass/main.scss"])
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({ match: "**/*.css" }))
}

function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    })
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('style'));
    gulp.watch('./*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload)
    gulp.watch('./js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload)
    gulp.watch(["./**/*.php"]).on('change', browserSync.reload)
}

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('style', 'watch'))


exports.style = style
exports.watch = watch
```

when I run gulp I get: Task never defined: style

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: When you are using the function style to define tasks, as you are, then you don't need to refer to them as strings.  So `gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel(style, watch))` is correct.  And same in your `watch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
exports.style = style
exports.watch = watch
exports.default = gulp.parallel(style, watch)
```

Comment: And at least reference my comment - and you missed the other mistake.  And the explanation.